# Data availability zones skipping AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create subnets per AZ per region in AWS. I'm able to read the [`aws_availability_zones` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/availability_zones.html) but when I iterate through the list it returns `us-west-1a` and `us-west-1c` (which doesn't exist).

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  count = length(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)

  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.cidr, 8, count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}
```

I expect it to return `us-west-1a` and `us-west-1b`.

It currently returns `us-west-1a` and `us-west-1c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Availability zones names are [randomised](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ram/latest/userguide/working-with-az-ids.html):

> To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones for a Region, we independently map Availability Zones to names for each account. For example, the Availability Zone us-east-1a for your AWS account might not have the same location as us-east-1a for another AWS account. For more information, see Regions and Availability Zones in the Amazon EC2 User Guide.
>
> To identify the location of your resources relative to your accounts, you must use the AZ ID, which is a unique and consistent identifier for an Availability Zone. For example, use1-az1 is an AZ ID for the us-east-1 Region and it is the same location in every AWS account.

`us-west-1` is a slightly weird region that has 2 availability zones: `usw1-az1` and `usw1-az3` and these are given randomly `a`, `b` or `c` per account.

```sh
aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-west-1
{
    "AvailabilityZones": [
        {
            "State": "available", 
            "ZoneName": "us-west-1a", 
            "Messages": [], 
            "ZoneId": "usw1-az3", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-1"
        }, 
        {
            "State": "available", 
            "ZoneName": "us-west-1b", 
            "Messages": [], 
            "ZoneId": "usw1-az1", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ran from another AWS account:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-west-1
{
    "AvailabilityZones": [
        {
            "State": "available", 
            "ZoneName": "us-west-1b", 
            "Messages": [], 
            "ZoneId": "usw1-az3", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-1"
        }, 
        {
            "State": "available", 
            "ZoneName": "us-west-1c", 
            "Messages": [], 
            "ZoneId": "usw1-az1", 
            "RegionName": "us-west-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know what happened to `usw1-az2` but it's not a valid AZ anymore and looking at an [old gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/tomelliff/e477cf6fb0a217773114bf7b51a39e1f) it hasn't been for a long time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I knew of the randomization of the naming for AZs just not us-west-1 splitting across a, b, c.